# Passagem de parâmetro laravel

Tags: php, laravel, rotas, laravel-rotas

Como passo 2 ou mais variáveis na rota?

View

```
<a href="{{route('transferir.edit', [$destino->servidor->idservidor, $destino->setor])}}" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" role="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span>Transferir</a>
```

Controller

```
public function edit($idservidor, $setorusuario)
{
    $servidor = Servidor::findOrFail($idservidor);

    $cargos = Cargo::orderBy('cargo')->pluck('cargo', 'idcargo');
    $setors = Setor::orderBy('setor')->pluck('setor', 'idsetor');

    return view('transferir.edit', compact('servidor','cargos','setors','setorusuario'));
}
```

Rota

```
Route::resource('/transferir', 'TransferirController');
Route::get('/transferir/{idservidor}/{setor}', 'TransferirController@edit');
```

Comment: Eai, jovem. Conseguiste resolver?

Comment: Retorna esse erro Type error: Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\TransferirController::edit(), 1 passed and exactly 2 expected

Comment: Mas você usou o que foi sugerido na resposta?

Comment: Sim, a url ficou assim http://localhost:8000/transferir/7882/edit?setor=CAD 
Estranho.

Comment: Tem certeza que usou exatamente igual? Perceba que eu editei e troquei **`idServidor`** para **`idservidor`**.

Comment: Resolvi usando sua solucao na view e alterando no controller a funcao
public function edit(request $setor, $idservidor)
    {   
 
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use um array associativo — [vide documentação](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#named-routes).

```
route('transferir.edit', ['idservidor' => $destino->servidor->idservidor, 
                          'setor' => $destino->setor]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se entendi muito bem , mas tente:

```
route('transferir.edit', ['idservidor' => $destino->servidor->idservidor, 
                          'setor' => $destino->setor
                         ]);
```

Comment: Redundante com a resposta anterior